# Multiple params HTACCESS

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Another question about htaccess

This rule:

```
RewriteRule ^page(.*)/(.*)$ mainpage.php?var1=$1&var2=$2
```

simply does not work as it should. When I visit `/page/var=something&var2=something` I get an empty value for var1 and a value for var2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^page(.*)/(.*)$ mainpage.php?var=$1&var=$2
```

Explanation of what it does:
When you go to `/page/var=something&var2=something`, apache replaces with you're given RegExp and makes it something like this: `mainpage.php?var=&var=var%3Dsomething%26var2%3Dsomething`. So, var will be an empty string (length is zero). By the way, you have two `var`  in your query string!

**Edit:**  Note that in example above (`/page/var=something&var2=something`) `$1` would be anything between `/page`  and `/var`  , and since nothing's there, you'll have an empty string!

**Edit 2**:

```
RewriteRule  /?page/var\=([^&]*)&var2\=([^&]*)    mainpage.php?var1=$1&var2=$2
```

Comment: I've updated the original code with var1 and var2 but it's still the same.

Comment: Okay, understood, so what would be the work around that? I'm new to regular expressions etc.

Comment: Okay, that worked. It seems a bit complicated but I guess I understand. So, with the first example I gave (or what I was using), what would be a scenario that would be used? Since that's what I thought it was for in the first place.

Comment: That can be used for pages like `pagebooks/TheLordOfTheRings`, then `var1` would be `books`, and `var2` would be `TheLordOfTheRings`. But I don't recommend using it since there are better choices.